# Disabling delegates in swift

Tags: swift, delegates, google-places-api

I currently have a text field called `searchTextField`. I also have two buttons called `firstButton` and `secondButton`. When I click `firstButton`, I enable the Google Places API in the action method by adding the relevant delegate `searchTextField.delegate=self`.

However, I would like it when I click `secondButton`, the Google Places API gets disabled and it's just a normal textfield. Is there a way to disable the delegate or another way to achieving the same result?

```
@IBAction func firstAction(_ sender: Any) {
    searchTextField.delegate=self //google autocomplete
}

@IBAction func secondAction(_ sender: Any) {
    searchTextField.placeholder = "Search without Google API"
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autoCompleteController.delegate = self

    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment
    autoCompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

    self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i would do this differently

```
var googleAPIEnable = false
func viewDidLoad() {
  searchTextField.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func firstAction(_ sender: Any) {
  googleAPIEnable = false
}

@IBAction func secondAction(_ sender: Any) {
  searchTextField.text = nil
  searchTextField.placeholder = "Search without Google API"
  googleAPIEnabled = true
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  guard googleAPIEnabled else {
    return true
  }

  let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
  autoCompleteController.delegate = self

  let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
  filter.type = .establishment
  autoCompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

  self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!